# Firefox: How to not append '.PART' to the file name of the currently downloading file, and just download the file with its normal filename

Tags: firefox

In Windows, when Firefox (I'm currently using 7.0) downloads a file, it appends `.PART` to the file name of the currently downloading file and just renames it to its original file name after it finishes downloading.

I sometimes like to watch a currently downloading video file, so it will be better if Firefox just downloads the file to its actual filename (like what Opera does), so I can easily double click the incompletely downloaded file and watch it with the video player assigned to that file extension, rather than the awkward 'Right click -> Open With -> Choose Default Program' route with .part files.

Does anyone know how to set Firefox to do this?

Comment: It may be possible, but I have never seen that option.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes. I think there is an `about:config` setting that I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It apparently cannot be done with the stock downloader.  Quoting a moderator from the major non-official Mozilla forum:

> [I think that would require a major rewrite of the downloader of 
>   firefox. You can try to replace it with another downloader like 
>   FlashGet.](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=1410275)

However, a user in that thread reports success using this tightly integrated downloader:

http://code.google.com/p/savefileto/