# Is it possible to stop firefox from adding ".part" to the currently downloading file's filename?

Tags: firefox

Right now, when I start a download, firefox creates `somefile.mp4` and `somefile.mp4.part`, writes all data into `.part` file, and when download is finished, renames `.part` file into `.mp4` file.
And I want to start watching an mp4 file as soon as it starts downloading. I can just open that `.part` file, but if that file is still open when download completes, firefox reports that download failed. It actually failes to save a bit of info at the end due to that, out of 23658496 byte file only 23560192 byte actually end up saved.

There is a similar question here, but it's 11 years old by now. [Firefox: How to not append '.PART' to the file name of the currently downloading file, and just download the file with its normal filename](https://superuser.com/questions/347753/firefox-how-to-not-append-part-to-the-file-name-of-the-currently-downloading)

There are a bunch of `browser.download` options in `about:config`, but I don't see anything useful there.

Comment: Logically; renaming (by firefox) a file that is in use (read by the viewer) would be similar to pull a rug out below your feet. *Guessing: This might be a filesystem restriction that is triggered by the reading task, which then gets reported as "cannot do that currently" to firefox - which treats it as a general "write error".*

Comment: Why use Firefox and not use a downloader product that doesn't rename the result?

Comment: And the answer to the question is probably: No, you would most likely need to change the source code, and recompile FF.

Comment: @Hannu Don't know about other oses, but it is possible to rename files that are currently open on windows, depends on flags passed to CreateFile.

Comment: @harrymc Can't find a free good proxy, and the only thing available to me only works in browsers.

Comment: @aiyo4930aiyo as implied above, may be dependent on the filesystem that is in use.

Comment: tried `Multithreaded Download Manager` firefox addon by jingyu9575, it seems it uses a temp folder. Maybe I can edit source code of that for my needs. Sounds easier than recompiling firefox itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mp4 files are really ..."special". Unless it's specifically encoded for streaming, you'd need the last piece of it to start playing anyway, so this wouldn't work. Use something like VLC for playback with the "Open in VLC media player" Firefox add-on.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).